# Identify which downstream job failed and send notification in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a wrapper job in Jenkins which will get triggered every hour if there are any new commits in my GIT repository. This wrapper job in turn calls 6 other downstream jobs. So the structure of my wrapper job (W) is like this:

W -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

I am using Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin to stitch one job to the other so that my upstream jobs fail if the downstream job fails. Upon completion of the last downstream job (F), Wrapper job (W) is copying the artifacts from all the downstream jobs in its current workspace.

Now when one of my downstream job (lets say E) fails, I get failure notifications from the failed downstream job (E) as well as from all the other upstream jobs (D, C, B, A and W). So I get 6 mails in total and it creates some noise.

If I activate the email notification on only the Wrapper job (W), then I get a single failure notification mentioning that Job A has failed. Then I will check Job A's logs only to find out that it was Job B that failed and continue the log checks until I reach Job E.

How can I customize the notification to send a single mail identifying the specific downstream job (in this case E) that caused the failure?

OR

Is there a better way to trigger the downstream jobs, wait for all the downstream jobs to get completed and copy the artifacts from all the downstream jobs to the trigger job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a Groovy script in Groovy Postbuild to iterate through all the subprojects of wrapper job and mark the wrapper job as failure if any of the subprojects have failed.

Also changed the exit criteria in "Trigger/call builds on other projects" to never mark job as failure/unstable. Instead the call of setting the job as failure is handled in the groovy script itself based on the status of the downstream subprojects.